# What's the right way to deal with spurious wakeup?

Tags: java, multithreading, wakeup

I am reading `Curator`'s source code, and found some code below:

```
            while ( (client.getState() == CuratorFrameworkState.STARTED) && !haveTheLock )
        {
            List<String>        children = getSortedChildren();
            String              sequenceNodeName = ourPath.substring(basePath.length() + 1); // +1 to include the slash

            PredicateResults    predicateResults = driver.getsTheLock(client, children, sequenceNodeName, maxLeases);
            if ( predicateResults.getsTheLock() )
            {
                haveTheLock = true;
            }
            else
            {
                String  previousSequencePath = basePath + "/" + predicateResults.getPathToWatch();

                synchronized(this)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        // use getData() instead of exists() to avoid leaving unneeded watchers which is a type of resource leak
                        client.getData().usingWatcher(watcher).forPath(previousSequencePath);
                        if ( millisToWait != null )
                        {
                            millisToWait -= (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis);
                            startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            if ( millisToWait <= 0 )
                            {
                                doDelete = true;    // timed out - delete our node
                                break;
                            }

                            wait(millisToWait);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wait();
                        }
                    }
                    catch ( KeeperException.NoNodeException e ) 
                    {
                        // it has been deleted (i.e. lock released). Try to acquire again
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I read javadoc from `Object` and should always check condition in loops, like this :

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (condition does not hold&)
        obj.wait(timeout);
         ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

which code is right?

Update

[Here](https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/master/curator-recipes/src/main/java/org/apache/curator/framework/recipes/locks/LockInternals.java#L262) is the source code of `Curator`.

Because `haveTheLock` is a local variable, no other thread would change it, so the code works fine.

Comment: The code above is very dangerous and it's quite difficult to ensure it's actually safe. For example, I don't see how it can avoid waiting for something that has already happened, which would be a disaster. It's possible it's safe because of the way other code works, but it's very hard to be sure. I would strongly recommend using the construct below unless you have absolutely no choice.

Comment: Duplicate of at least 2 other StackOverflow answers. 
Please check http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/01/08/how-to-work-with-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in-java/

AND

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/concurrency-best-practices.html#wait

Answer (score 0):

The synchronized block *is* within a while loop.

And it has two branches:

- an infinite `wait()`: no condition to check
- a timed `wait(millisToWait)` and the amount of millis to wait is recalculated at each loop

So spurious wakeups won't really have an effect. The main reason to have the while loop *inside* the synchronized block as in the javadoc is that very often you need the synchronization to make sure the result of the condition is visible.

In the code you show, I means that both `client.getState()` and `haveTheLock` should be thread safe (for example volatile variables).

Comment: There is another reason to have the loop inside the synchronized block:  It is to prevent _lost notification_.  If the test happens outside of the same synchronized block that contains the wait() call then; thread A could perform the test, and decide it needs to wait(), thread B could change the condition and call notify(), and then thread A could enter a wait() call for which the notify() has already been given... and lost.  Thread A then never wakes up.

Comment: you mean the order of  `while`  and `synchronized ` does not affect spurious weakup?

Comment: @znlyj Not in this case, assuming the condition in the while is visible. But james large made a very good point.

Comment: I add source code link, I don't understand why `Curator` implement in this way.